# How to change class attributes using a method?

Tags: python, class

I have a Django model class who has some default attributes, and I want to change the value of the `complete` variable by calling a function:

```
class Foo:
    complete = False

    def set_complete_true():
        complete = True
```

But after calling `set_complete_true()` the `complete` variable is still `False`.

Comment: Make `set_complete_true` an instance method and do `self.complete = True` instead

Answer (score 4, accepted):

An *instance* function (most functions *are* instance functions) has a special parameter that is always the first one called `self`. It is a reference to the object with which you call the function. For example, if you call `some_instance.foo()`, then `foo` is called with as `self` the `some_instance`.

You thus need to add the `self` parameter, and set the `self.complete` to `True`:

```
class Foo:
    complete = False

    def set_complete_true(self):
        self.complete = True
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe this is worth a shot:

```
class Foo:
    complete = False

    def set_complete_true(self):
        self.complete = True

a = Foo()
a.set_complete_true()
print(a.complete) # should be True now
```